# Allign images in same line

Tags: html, css

Please someone help me as i am learning web development.I am facing two problems
1:How can i allign all the images in same line as my last image goes down
2:the price beneath image  i want to aliign right on the last corner of images

```
    [<section id ="featured">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\psdword\images/thumb-1.jpg">
                    <a href="">Fugiat nulla sint</a>
                    <span>$30</span>
                    <span class="rating"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\psdword\images/thumb2.jpg">
                    <a href="">Daute irure dolor</a>
                    <span>$24</span>
                    <span class="rating"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\psdword\images/thumb3.jpg">
                    <a href="">Officia deserunt mollit</a>
                    <span>$60</span>
                    <span class="rating"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\psdword\images/thumb4.jpg">
                    <a href="">Pim minim veniam</a>
                    <span>$17</span>
                    <span class="rating"></span>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </section>

    #featured ul{
    padding: 0;
}
#featured li{
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 1%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#featured li img{
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
#featured li a{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}
#featured li span{
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    color: #333;
}
#featured ul:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Kindly look at this image
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVHO0.png)

Comment: Please post 1 issue per question. Why do you have `[<section ` ..?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block`to `#featured li`and remove the `float:left`

Comment: It did not worked.Kindly look at the screenshot below you will have a better idea what i want

Comment: probably you should set the `#featured li img` width to 100%

Answer (score 1):

The parent container must be wide enough to display all images in one row or it will wrap image(s) to a new row.  Check the width of the parent element.  You might adjust the parent width or the images to make them fit.

Keep in mind responsive web design.  In other words, how is the page going to render on a smartphone, or tablet?  You might not be able to display in one row for all device types.

A UI framework/library can help here.  Grid layouts are widely used for this purpose.  See Bootstrap or Material Design Lite.

Answer (score 1):

> Keep in mind responsive web design. In other words, how is the page going to render on a smartphone, or tablet? You might not be able to display in one row for all device types.

You could use flex-box in order to let the elements use as much rows as they need for the user's screen size:

```
ul{  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I also wouldn't Set the width of the li on percentages. On a phone this would become really really small.

In order to align the span you could just make the width of the li as big as the width of the img